# Substitution between two patterns with line offset via sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a big file with content separated by headers.

How would I go about substituting the text between the line after a particular header and the line before a specific string (non-inclusive) in the file via sed or awk?

Example: I want to replace the text between the line after `header1` and the line before`string_near_end_of_file` (non-inclusive) with `EXAMPLE` in the file below...

```
...

header1
#######
content1

header2
#######
content2

...

string_near_end_of_file

...
```

Intended outcome:

```
...

header1
#######
EXAMPLE

string_near_end_of_file

...
```

I know that `sed '/pattern1/,/.. pattern2/c\substition_string'` file substitutes `substition_string` between `pattern1` and `pattern2` and that `sed -n '/pattern/{n;p}' file` prints the line after the `pattern` match but I'm not sure now to put this together to achieve my stated goal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/string_near_end_of_file/{p=0} !p; $1=="header1"{p=1; print "######\nEXAMPLE\n"}' file
```

**Output:**

```
...

header1
######
EXAMPLE

string_near_end_of_file

...
```

Comment: Have just updated my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: check my updated answer as per your edited question.

Comment: Thanks! Before I accept your answer I was just wondering what you would do if `header1` contained a space (like so: `header 1`)? I've just realised that I made a mistake in my question and that I should have mentioned that the headers contain spaces - apologies for that!

Comment: If there are spaces in header value, then you can use it like this: `awk '/string_near_end_of_file/{p=0} !p; /header 1/{p=1; print "######\nEXAMPLE\n"}' file`

Comment: Yep. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed:

`sed -e '/header1/,/string_near/{/header1/{n;s/$/\nEXAMPLE\n/;n};/string_near/!d}' file`

In the range:

- `/header1/{n;` - skip the header1 line

  - `s/$/\nEXAMPLE\n/;` - replace the ### end of line with `\nEXAMPLE\n`
  - `n}` leave the ### and EXAMPLE lines alone
- `/string_near/!d;` - delete other lines except string_near

sed sucks for requirements to repeat the /START/,/END/ patterns within the block.  You can sometimes use `//` to mean the last regex, but any nested regexes limit its use in /START/,/END/ ranges.

Note that some sed implementations require semicolons before closing curly braces.

Note also that I use replacement of the line end `s/$/\nEXAMPLE\n/` because it is much easier to inline at the command line then it is to use sed's `c` `a` or `i` commands, which require a newline in the command string.

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** solution (assuming that *header* line is always followed by `#######` line):

```
awk -v repl="EXAMPLE" '!f && /header/{ f=1; n=NR; getline nl; r=$0 ORS nl }
       /string_near_end_of_file/{ f=0; print r ORS repl ORS ORS $0; next }
       f && NR>n{ next }1' file
```

The output:

```
...

header1
#######
EXAMPLE

string_near_end_of_file

...
```